# Visual Studio 2013 windows forms application with Resource file using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, scheduled-tasks, windows-forms-designer

I have created windows forms application in C# VS 2013 with resource file (to maintain configurations). I created a Task in 'windows task scheduler' with the exe of the application (I copied 'exe file and resouce related file' to another envirnonment). when I run task, its running without any issues.

My intention of using resource file is to change configurations at any time without building the application.

But when I change configurations in application, if I update resource file in above mentioned environment,  application using old configurations. when I copy new exe file its working with new configurations.

Please let me know is it correct way or guide me how to schedule 'windows forms application' in 'windows task scheduler' with resource file.

Thanks in advance,
Krishna.

Comment: hi, did you find my answer useful?

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing resx files and config files. You should use the second one. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is good example.

Answer (score 0):

Outside of ASP.NET, there isn't an easy way to use resource files in this way, resource files (.resx) are XML files which are build into a binary formal .resrouce file and embedded into the application assembly during build time, this is why any changes are ignored.

However you can put settings in your .config file in the appsettings section or build your own configsection, this way when the application runs again it will read the settings with your changes from this file.

You can also have a custom Xml/Json/Ini file and read from it using with your own code, but for simple settings, use appsettings section in the app.config file.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903313(v=vs.71).aspx